# Logstash when launched as service keeps restarting

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash

So I had the exact same issue as described in https://discuss.elastic.co/t/consistent-restarts-of-logstash-with-high-cpu-recorded/86597:

I'm running Logstash as a service on Ubuntu. And I'm launching it by

```
sudo systemctl start logstash.service
```

My task was simple: import data from jdbc (MySQL) into Elasticsearch in a one shot manner (so no scheduling option. no cron timer). So as in the link above, I'm using a JDBC input filter. And the elasticsearch output filter.

I managed to get it to work well when I launched logstash directly through command line (logstash -f conf_file): logstash starts, imports the data and shutdown. Just as expected.

Now, when I tried to do the same when I was launching logstash as a service, it would keep importing the data and restarting over and over again.

The link above provide a solution but it's actually wrong. It says that when no "schedule" option is specified, a default 1 minute timer is used. This is in direct contradiction with what the documentation says [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc-schedule):

> There is no schedule by default. If no schedule is given, then the
>   statement is run exactly once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I think is the explanation:
when logstash is launched as a service and the config file has no "schedule" option, once it has finished importing the data, logstash simply shutdowns by itself. The problem is that because it was started as a service, the service manager (systemctl) detects that the service is offline and "resurrect it" over and over again.

When a schedule option is used, the service says alive and therefore, there is no issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is another case: logstash keeps restarting when the logstash conf file is not written correctly, so if you have this issue, first check if the syntaxe is correct